Deploying SonarQube with Helm on K8S
I've deployed SonarQube on on-prem K8S with Helm using this repo: https://github.com/SonarSource/helm-chart-sonarqube/tree/master/charts/sonarqube.
My values.yaml looks like that:
service:
  type: NodePort
  port: 9000
  nodePort: 30000

ingress:
  enabled: false


persistence:
  enabled: true
  storageClass: "local-path"
  size: 10Gi


postgresql:
  postgresqlPassword: "randompass"
  persistence:
    storageClass: "local-path"

account:
  currentAdminPasswordSecretName: sonarqube-admin-secret  # The secret containing the current admin password
  adminPasswordSecretName: sonarqube-admin-secret  # The secret containing the new admin password

When I deploy this
helm upgrade --install sonarqube sonarqube/sonarqube -n sonarqube -f values.yaml

2 pods are created : sonarqube-postgresql-0 and sonarqube-sonarqube-0. When I exec into postgresql pod and run psql -U sonarUser -d sonarDB and provide my randompass, my logins fails. However, when I use the default password, sonarPass I'm able to connect to database. Could somebody point me what Im doing wrong?

What is the value of Values.jdbcOverwrite.enabled in your values.yaml file?
